# Infinite scroll with no content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Maybe this is just me thinking of a way to create a really obnoxious "Site under construction" page, but is there anyway to create an infinite scroll when you don't actually have any content? So essentially, you would just scroll down a white page forever?

Would it work to simply use two page and constantly "refetch" the other page each time you approach the bottom of the one you're currently on? This might be a terrible idea from the memory standpoint of the browser, but I thought with only two pages that may not be an issue.

Comment: Why not just keep appending a div that has a height and width .. That should work just fine

Comment: It would be interesting to see at what point that would cause any effect on the memory usage of the browser...if ever?

Comment: I'm confused. If there isn't any content why would there even be a scroll bar? If you create divs dynamically, what do you want the scroll bar to do (e.g. change size, jump to the middle of the page, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you will need such thing but you can increase the height while scrolling by the amount you scrolled or such thing

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height(); 
var oldScrollTop = 0 ; 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').height(windowHeight+50); 
})

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(); 
var newHeight = windowHeight + scrollTop; 
    if(scrollTop > oldScrollTop)
    {
        oldScrollTop = scrollTop; 
        $('body').height(newHeight); 
    }
});
```

Check this fiddle out http://jsfiddle.net/Lx563/